# Processing events from Event Log and react on a certain pattern (Rx?)

Tags: system.reactive, event-log

I need to process events coming from the EventLog. This is easy using the [EventLogWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671202%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) attaching to the EventRecordWritten event. However the query I am interested in (eventid == 299 || eventid == 500) provides more events than what I need. Here is an example of the stream

```
Event ID   Correlation ID
299        1AD...  (this is actually a guid)  X1
500        1AD...                             X2
500        1AD...
500        1AD...
299        43B...                             Y1
299        EDB...                             Z1
500        43B...                             Y2
500        EDB...                             Z2
500        43B...
500        43B...
```

I am interested in the event 299 and the first event 500 that matches the correlation id of the 299 event. I marked them in the stream above, that's the output collection I am interested in: `[X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Z1, Z2]` which probably is a dictionary using the correlation id as a key and a tuple of `EventRecord` as the value

```
{ 1AD.., <X1, X2> }
{ 43B.., <Y1, Y2> }
{ EDB.., <Z1, Z2> }
```

In general events might come in order (299 and then 500) but in a high concurrency situation I foresee two 299 events coming together and then the 500 events so I don't want to rely on the order the events come. The correlation id is the key to correlate them (which is the first property of the event `eventRecord.Properties[0]`)

I think this can be solved with a state machine but it would be interesting to see if anyone comes up with a solution with Rx represented by a query to an observable. That would keep the pattern matching logic in a single place.

**UPDATE**: here is the answer to the solution. Thanks Gideon it was exactly the starting point I needed!

```
var pairs = events
            .Where(e299 => e299.EventArgs.EventRecord.Id == 299)
            .SelectMany(e299 => events.Where(e500 => e500.EventArgs.EventRecord.Id == 500 &&
                                                    e299.EventArgs.EventRecord.Properties[0].Value.ToString() ==
                                                    e500.EventArgs.EventRecord.Properties[0].Value.ToString())
                                    .Take(1), 
                        (e299, e500) => new { First = e299, Second = e500 });
```

Thanks in advance,
Matias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the 299 events always come before the 500 events, `SelectMany` and `Where` should be enough.

```
var events; //declared somewhere

var pairs = from e299 in events
            where e299.eventid == 299
            from e500 in events
            where e500.eventid == 500 &&
                  e299.Correlation == e500.Correlation
            select new with {Correlation = e299.Correlation,
                             First = e299,
                             Second = e500}
```

If your source has multiple 500 events for each correlated 299 event, you may need to switch to lambda syntax and add a `Take(1)` to the second subscription.

Comment: spot on! Thanks Gideon... the query using lambda and take(1) was included in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You should look at using Observable.When, with Joins. This will allow you to compose complex join patterns like you desire.

For example see, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3868608/13131 and [Guide to System.Reactive.Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596140/guide-to-system-reactive-joins).

Comment: I tried using And and When but wasn't able to achieve the right behavior. I'm sure it can be solved somehow, still need more practice with RX :). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with "a state machine".

But you could write an observer that collects (eventid == 299 || eventid == 500). Using throttle strategy (collect the lastest 1000 events, or the latest minute, I don't know), it raise an event when it detects a pair of events 299, 500 have the same guid, removing then from its internal dictionary/list of events.

Then, that kind observer IS THE observable for the rest of your system.

Maybe a list could be collect the events, and when a new event is detected, something like

events.Where(e => e.eventid == newevent.eventid && ((e.id == 299 && newev.id == 500) || (e.id == 500 && newev.id == 299))

could be enough in performance, instead of having a dictionary by guid.

See you later, Mathew!

Comment: Thanks Angel... Buffering the events and analyze them was my first approach. I wanted something pure RX.