# Aggregation and Joins (Inner, Outer, Left, ...) with TPL-Dataflow?

Tags: c#, .net, join, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Is there any better way to implement functions like aggregation within a TPL-Dataflow mesh than using a `BatchBlock` to buffer all items until completion, emit them as a collection and then use a transform block to do the actual aggregation?

Similarly, is there any other way to do an inner/outer/left/right join of two datasets without using a `BatchedJoinBlock` to buffer all items of both datasources, emit them as a tuple of two collections and then do the actual join with a Transform block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. There is no such mechanism out-of-the-box in `TPL Dataflow`, as aggregation and joining operations aren't about `flowing`, they are about querying the data.

However, as the [blocks are perfectly fit with `RX` library](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2013/01/31/mixing-tpl-dataflow-with-reactive-extensions/), you can use the [Join Patterns in Rx](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ca3a0d4-ac61-4325-9fa2-ed622830b518/join-patterns-in-rx?forum=rx) paradigm while aggregating your data.

More related links:

- [Aggregation](http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#Aggregation) in `Rx`
- [Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx): Take action once all events are completed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3867858/213550)
- [Guide to System.Reactive.Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9596140/213550)

Comment: So I guess it's the same for grouping then too?

Comment: It's not the same, as Rx not a part of dataflow library, but near enough.